# Get the number of files in a directory using AJAX in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to get the number of images in a directory using JS and AJAX (in my chrome extension). How can I do this? I've added my current code below. It doesn't seem to be working since I'm not getting the alert.

**main.js**

```
...
$.ajax({
    url: "/images-folder-on-server/",
    success: function (data) {
        var image_count = $(data).length(); 
        alert(image_count);
    }
});
```

**main.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>New Tab</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/octicons/octicons.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1 id = "greet">Hello,''.</h1>

  <div id="clock"></div>


    <script src = "main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "description": "Add description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "main.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "main.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Background image"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: Good for you, and _your problem is?.._ Please take a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: No problem as long as you're willing to improve it!

Comment: @Xan Do I need to add anything else?

Comment: Well, remarks: never reuse code like that in an extension (`main.js` shouldn't do the same thing in the background AND in the new tab override). If your `success` isn't called, well, doesn't that mean it's not succeeding? Add an error handler and see what it gives.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ajax call is made from background page, don't forget add the remote server url to `permissions`.

```
"permissions": ["Complete_Images_Server_Url"]
```